# Execute a for loop for certain integers and store the values for each iteration

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to execute a for loop for different integers and store the values of each loop in a matrix. How do I do this in MATLAB?
For eg. i have to run the for loop for the values

```
for i=36,48,72,120
end
```

if each loop gives a 1-by-36 matrix as output, I have to get a 4-by-36 matrix. That is for each value of i.

Comment: You should show what you have tried and didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Store the integers in a vector and iterate over this vector:

```
values = [36,48,72,120];

num = numel(values);

per_iteration_size = 36;
result = zeros(num, per_iteration_size);

for k=1:num
    % store the "results" in the result vector
    % in this example, we just store [values(k), values(k), ...]
    result(k,:) = values(k)*ones(per_iteration_size,1);
end
```

Depending on what happens per loop iteration, this often can be done without using any loop at all. This is called [vectorization](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and often notably improves processing time.